# Tensorflow-directml is not making any processing time difference

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I don't see any time difference when running tensorflow-directml on intel HD hardware. Can someone help me on why running on a GPU is not making any difference? Am I executing the code correctly?

**System Information:**

- Windows 10 - Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz 2.81 GHz
- Python Version = 3.6.
- TensorFlow-DirectML Version 21.2.2
- Graphics card driver version - Intel(R) HD Graphics 520

**Code to reproduce the issue**

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
layers.Dense(4096,activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(4096,activation='relu'),
layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
metrics=['accuracy'],)

model.fit(np.expand_dims(x_train,3), y_train, epochs=2, batch_size=1024)
```

**Logs**
*GPU Usage*
[image]
*CPU Usage*
[image]

Comment: I suspect that it is simply because the GPU you have (the intel integrated graphics processor) is not that powerful when compared with dedicated graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

Received a response from tensorflow-directml team

https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml/issues/377

"Although tensorflow-directml can run on most hardware that supports D3D12, we unfortunately cannot guarantee that the performance will be better than the CPU, especially when using old hardware or integrated graphics. The Intel HD Graphics 520 is an example of hardware where we haven't seen great results compared to the CPU."